# Check if rsync command ran successful

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

The following bash-script is doing a rsync of a folder every hour:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -r -z -c /home/pi/queue root@server.mine.com:/home/foobar
rm -rf rm /home/pi/queue/*
echo "Done"
```

But I found out that my Pi disconnected from the internet, so the rsync failed. So it did the following command, deleting the folder.
How to determine if a rsync-command was successful, if it was, then it may remove the folder.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Usually, any Unix command shall return 0 if it ran successfully, and non-0 in other cases.

Look at man rsync for exit codes that may be relevant to your situation, but I'd do that this way :

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -r -z -c /home/pi/queue root@server.mine.com:/home/foobar && rm -rf rm /home/pi/queue/* && echo "Done"
```

Which will rm and echo done only if everything went fine.

Other way to do it would be by using $? variable which is always the return code of the previous command :

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -r -z -c /home/pi/queue root@server.mine.com:/home/foobar
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
  rm -rf rm /home/pi/queue/*
  echo "Done"
else
  echo "Error while running rsync"
fi
```

see *man rsync*, section **EXIT VALUES**

Comment: Should I use ```if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]``` or ```if [[ $? -gt 0 ]] ```? Because the latest is the resultcode regarding the rsync documentation.

Comment: both work fine. [ is a shell syntax, [[ is bash-specific, and the first compare the exit code to 0, the other one to non-zero, and the if is reverse, so both are working fine and doing exactly the same here \o/

Answer (score 13):

Old question but I am surprised nobody has given the simple answer:

   Use the **--remove-source-files** rsync option. 

I think it is exactly what you need.

From the man page:

```
--remove-source-files   sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
```

Only files that rsync has fully successfully transferred are removed.

When unfamiliar with rsync it is easy to be confused about the --delete options and the --remove-source-files option. The --delete options remove files on the destination side. More info here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/156664/what-are-the-differences-between-the-rsync-delete-options

Answer (score 10):

you need to check the exit value of rsync

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -r -z -c /home/pi/queue root@server.mine.com:/home/foobar
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]] 
then
   # take failure action here
else
   rm -rf rm /home/pi/queue/*
   echo "Done"
fi
```

Set of result codes here:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync